# Hide Number Count Total in SharePoint Modern Experience List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, modern-experience, group-by

I have a list in SharePoint modern experience, and my customer wants the total count, which appears in parenthesis (), to not display.

I've seen scripts that work for 2013 or 2010, but using the SharePoint Online modern Experience is different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing the total count? can you please attach any screenshot if possible? If it is the count of items in list view then you can hide it from list view settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I just edited my post to include a screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities as there is no configuration setting to hide the count of grouping.

**Documentation**: [Use grouping to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-grouping-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7)

You will need custom solution for this using [SharePoint framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

One way to achieve this is using **Application customizer** [SPFx extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) to inject custom CSS in your modern page and hide the grouping item count.

**Reference**: [Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)

---

**Update from comments**:

This is now possible using SharePoint JSON formatting. Try using below JSON code in [View formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting) settings:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
    "groupProps": {
        "headerFormatter": {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "@group.fieldData"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s the kind of information I’ve read.  Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately I’m not the site owner, just a contractor working on this specific list.  I’m not sure what a SharePoint framework is.  They said I should use their “Modern Script Editor”.  Just to test, I temporarily switched the list to classic view, and the JavaScript I wrote worked perfectly.  The script doesn’t seem to work in this Modern Script Editor...which I’ve never heard of.

Comment: This is now possible with JSON formatting. Check [this(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#build-custom-group-headers-and-footers).]

Comment: Ganesh, this is great news.  Thank you.  So I’ll be able to hide the group by number counts in ( )  in a modern view with this?  Could I also hide the column headers?  

Also, I hate to be a bother and sound too much like a novice, but could you please tell me what I would write to accomplish this?  Again, thank you so much.

Comment: You need to customize list view using JSON formatting capabilities of SharePoint. You can hide the count as well as you can format group headers conditionally to apply colors, icons & much more. Check the examples given in [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#build-custom-group-headers-and-footers).

Comment: Thanks again, Ganesh.  This GroupBy list doesn't have any headers above, just an arrow, column header, colon, then the FAQ question.  For example:                                            >Question: How Do I Check Out Books? (1)         When clicked it drops down to reveal the answer.  But I'm trying to get rid of the "Question:" and the (1).  The list you sent is comprehensive with a lot of good information, but I can't find anything specific about my issue.

Comment: The most important thing is to try and get rid of the number counts, to be honest.  Everything I wrote in the classic experience worked perfectly, so I'm kinda trying everything I can think of for this modern page to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this using JSON? Check my updated answer & use the JSON I provided. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh.  Yes your suggestion worked perfectly.